# QgsRasterLayer xyz_tiles asks for the same tiles again

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, xyz-tiles

I create a qgis-plugin with pyqis.

I create a raster layer of xyz-tiles server with following code

```py
        layer = QgsRasterLayer(self.url, layer_name, "wms")
        
        if layer.isValid():
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        else:
            print("Layer failed to load!")
```

The layer asks for the same tiles. How can I make qgis remember the tiles it recieves and stop asking them again.